# Zend Framework: ERR (3): syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Trying to run Zend Framework application but receiving this error:

```
2017-07-30T18:40:50+03:00 ERR (3): syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file
```

In file it highlighs there is just following:

```
<? if (count($this->tickets)) : ?>
<tbody class="tickets">
<?php foreach ($this->tickets as $ticket) : ?>
...
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
<?php endif;?>
```

Could anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the opening of the PHP tag. Replace `<? if (...` with `<?php if (...` on the first line.

Or you can also set `short_open_tag=On` in the php.ini configuration file.